# Text analysis Word Counter Java

Tags: java, word-count

I need to write code that reads and does a text analysis of a file. One of the things it needs to do is to count how many words there are in the file. I wrote a method `countWords`, but when I run the program it returns 0. The text file I am using contains the following:

> > Ask not what your country can do for you
> >     ask what you can do for your country

So it clearly should return 17 and not 0. What did I do wrong?

```
public class TextAnalysis {

public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
    File in01 = new File("a5_testfiles/in01.txt");
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(in01);

    System.out.println("TEXT FILE STATISTICS");
    System.out.println("--------------------");
    System.out.println("Length of the longest word: " + longestWord(fileScanner));
    System.out.println("Number of words in file wordlist: " );
    countWords(fileScanner);


}

public static String longestWord (Scanner s) {
    String longest = "";
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        String word = s.next();
        if (word.length() > longest.length()) {
            longest = word;
        }
    }

    return (longest.length() + " " + "(\"" + longest + "\")");
}

public static void countWords (Scanner s) throws IOException {
    int count = 0;

        while(s.hasNext()) {
            String word = s.next();
                count++;
        }

    System.out.println(count);


}
```

Comment: Don't reuse the scanner.

Comment: What does `longestWord(Scanner s)`, output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already read the scanner and reading it again. just create another scanner to use in count words method

```
 fileScanner = new Scanner(<your file object>);
```

before

```
 countWords(fileScanner);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great.. have fun coding :)

Answer (score 1):

try this?

```
void countWords()
{
          String temp;
          File path = new File("c:/Bala/");//give ur path
          File file = new File(path, "Bala.txt");//give ur filename
          FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
          char cbuf[] = new char[(int) file.length()];
          fr.read(cbuf);
          temp = new String(cbuf);
          String count[]=test.split("\\s");
          System.out.println("Count:"+t.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a new scanner for your count words method, the problem lies under s.next(); it reads the next word in your buffer and discard the previous ones, so after you called your longest word method, the scanner buffer has been used up.